# import java classes into jsp project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I have a jsp project and I am using eclipse.  I want to import a couple of external java source code into Java Resources src.  Is there a way to do it rather than create a couple of new classes and then copy and paste the code into it?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're already in the expected package layout for source files, you can just File|Import from the Filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually nobody is getting what if one havn't define package ???
then define package in ur java code as :-

```
 package MyPackage;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.Map.Entry;


    public class NavBackend {

            static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
            {  
                ..............
                ..............



    then in your jsp file you can write like :

<%@page import="MyPackage.NavBackend"%>
```